# Creating new groups by pattern

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have JSON with data about some products and I have already converted this into flat table by pandas, so now I have a few columns with data. I Selected some products manually and putted them into one group. I have sorted them by name for example but this is more complicated, there are also some features and requirements which need to be checked.
So what I want is to create script which will group my products in familiar way as those few groups I created manually based on my own thoughts.
Im totally new into machine learning, but I read about this and also watched some tutorials, but I haven't seen this type of case. 
I saw that if I use KNN classifier for example, I have to put in input every group that exists and then it will assign single product to one of those groups, but in my case this must be more complicated I guess since I want from this script to create those groups on his own in similiar way to selected by me.

I was thinking about unsupervised machine learnign but this doesn't look like solution beacuse I have my own data which I want to provide, it seems like I need to use some kind of hybrid with supervised machine learning.

```
data = pd.read_json('recent.json')['results']
data = json_normalize(data)
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
product_name = le.fit_transform(data['name'])
```

just some code to show what I have done

I don't know if that makes sense what I want, I already made attempt to this problem in normal way without machine learning just by If and loop things, but I wish I could do that also in "smarter" way

Answer (score 0):

the code above shows nothing. If you have data about some products like each entry contains fields you can clasterize this with KNN what is an unsupervides method.

> I have to put in input every group that exists

Not, just define the metric between two entries and the method makes classes or entire dendrogram according to that, so you can select classes from dendrogramm as you want. If you look at each node there, it contains common feature of items in class, so it makes auto-description for a class.